# Phing ssh capture the command result strange result

Tags: phing

I have a simple Phing script, which should ssh to server, do something and return the result, like so:

```
<project name="test" default="update">
<target name="update">
<ssh host="${db:host}" username="${db:host:ssh:user}" password="${db:host:ssh:password}" command="echo 'OK' &amp;&amp; echo 'NOOK'" display="true" property="ssh:result"/>
    <echo msg="result: ${ssh:result}"/>
</target>
</project>
```

I'd expect the result to be 'NOOK', however the actual result is:

```
     [echo] result: OK
NOOK
```

I am kind of puzzled, as I am interested in the value of the last command executed, not the first. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

The result is correct. Your command is to echo 'OK' and if it passed without error it should echo 'NOOK'.

```
echo 'OK' && echo 'NOOK'; # result is "OK\nNOOK"
```

If you want result of previous command it should look like:

```
(exit $? && echo 'OK') || echo 'NOOK'
```

It should show result of previous command. You can replace exit $? with any command of you want to know result.

EDIT: Problem is in bash not in phing... If you want to know result of last phing command, you should study http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/apbs17.html and how to get return value of the phing command you want to know result.